# Redirect 301 all my images on htaccess Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect 301 all my images on htaccess of my site in Wordpress..
I have 2 different paths for images

The Old path of the images is:
1) https://www.informarea.it/IMAGES%2F2016%2F10%2FLogo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg.jpgx
2) https://www.informarea.it/image.axd?picture=%2F2014%2F12%2Fwhatsapp-emoji.jpg

The New path of the images must be the same:
1) https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg
2) https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2014/12/whatsapp-emoji.jpg

What should I write in the htaccess?
Can you help me?
Thank you
Fabrizio

Comment: Why is old URL showing `%2F` instead of `/`

Comment: I don't know. Before my CMS was Blogengine.net, I took this wrong path from the search console...

Comment: Can you place a .htaccess inside `images/` folder if needed?

Comment: images folder now don't exist, what is your code solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule as first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^images/(.+?)(?:\.jpgx)?$ /wp-content/uploads/upload/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} picture=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^image\.axd$ /wp-content/uploads/upload/%1? [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Then try `https://www.informarea.it/IMAGES/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg.jpgx` in a new browser to test.

Comment: Thanks, i will try, bu for second redirect 301? It's right this?
RewriteRule ^image.axd?$ /wp-content/uploads/upload/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]

Comment: Hello anubhava, your code work but I must leave also .jpgx

Comment: yes... file must to be https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg

Comment: result must to be https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg

Comment: this url https://www.informarea.it/IMAGES/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg.jpgx must redirect to this  https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2016/10/Logo-Game-Aggiuntive-23.jpg

Comment: your code works but you need to remove the final .jpgx extension

Comment: FROM https://www.informarea.it/image.axd?picture=%2F2014%2F12%2Fwhatsapp-emoji.jpg TO https://www.informarea.it/wp-content/uploads/upload/2014/12/whatsapp-emoji.jpg

Comment: second stay like this https://www.test.informarea.it/image.axd?picture=/2017/07/come-inviare-su-whatsapp-file-da-PC.jpg,  does not redirect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165308/discussion-between-anubhava-and-fabry19dice).

Comment: then search console report these URL as not found but as you can see they have %2F instead of /...

Comment: Strange, first redirect perfect, second don't redirect... but search console report URL with %2F and not / .. What do you think? code must be with %2F or not?

Comment: Ideally `%2F` should not be there. It should all be `/`